# Is ‘red’ an abstract noun?

Tags: abstract-nouns

I think that a color is intangible and a paint (thing) is concrete but a color (property) is abstract. Isn’t ‘color’ itself an abstract noun? I cannot imagine a red color but only a red-colored thing.

Comment: *Justice* is an even more abstract concept than color, but I'll bet you have some fairly concrete notions about what it might be. In any case, colors can be perceived by the senses, which makes them pretty concrete.

Comment: Who says *abstract* is not gradable? But that brings up another thought, which is that you seem to be looking for an argument, not an answer.

Comment: @Robusto Sorry….

Comment: @Robusto Could you forgive me…?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Check the archives - the question may have been raised before on EL&U.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are these words concrete or abstract nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/485398/are-these-words-concrete-or-abstract-nouns) Different nouns involved, but the same overarching answer: 'When it comes down to it, there's no entirely satisfying [and certainly no universally agreed] way to define _concrete_ and _abstract_.... The concept of concrete and abstract nouns does not hold up to serious scrutiny.' [Juhasz] Elsewhere, someone (it could have been me) wrote that the terms have been largely binned by serious linguists.

Comment: 'I cannot imagine a red color but only a red-colored thing.' ... Sometimes, I have migraines with visual accompaniments, made clearer if I shut my eyes. These include ... I can only call them flags, like pennants on cables (but at crazy angles). These are usually coloured, often bicolored like naval pennants. / Sometimes there is only a general 'haze' of say a red hue. /  But 'redness' is primarily a psychological phenomenon, often of course triggered by light, perhaps from a red object.